# My hard drive is not showing up on my computer (Windows)

Tags: windows, mac, backup, storage

On both my mac and my windows desktop, my Seagate Backup drive is not showing up anywhere. On my windows computer, the only place I can see it is in the devices tab but I can't open it up to see the files on it. If anyone knows how to fix this  please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like the HDD has failed

Comment: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](//superuser.com/q/241817) is worth a read (but I don't think it answers your particular question).

Comment: @Ramhound My hard drive, when plugged in, causes the computer to make the sound that it normally does when something is plugged in.

Comment: Just because the usb host controller detects a device being connected doesn’t mean your HDD is functional

Comment: Does the physical drive show up under Disk Management?

Comment: The USB controller could be bad, the hard drive could be bad, or the drive could be encrypted. You need to separate the drive from the USB enclosure and access the drive directly to determine what the next steps are. Most likely the drive is bad though. I can’t emphasize enough how terrible Seagate hard drives are. If there is any question the drive may have failed, the odds are extremely high it did.